# Uno Platform Remove Right Spacing from NavigationView

Tags: navigationview, winui-3, uno-platform

I'm having an issue with NavigationView control, where it doesn't align with the center and keeps weird spacing at the right.[image]

My code for NavigationView is:

```
    <NavigationView
                Background="Red"
                PaneDisplayMode="Top"
                IsSettingsVisible="False"
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                >

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Tag="SamplePage1" Icon="Library"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Search" Tag="SamplePage5" Icon="Shop" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Search" Tag="SamplePage5" Icon="Shop" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Search" Tag="SamplePage5" Icon="Shop"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem but I managed to find a solution:

```
<NavigationView.Resources>              
    <x:Doublex:Key="TopNavigationViewPaneCustomContentMinWidth">0</x:Double>
</NavigationView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can stretch `MenuItems`. You can avoid that right space using the `FooterMenuItems`.

```xml
<NavigationView
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Background="Red"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
    IsSettingsVisible="False"
    PaneDisplayMode="Top">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="Home"
            Icon="Library"
            Tag="SamplePage1" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="Search"
            Icon="Shop"
            Tag="SamplePage5" />
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="Search"
            Icon="Shop"
            Tag="SamplePage5" />
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="Search"
            Icon="Shop"
            Tag="SamplePage5" />
    </NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

**UPDATE**

You also can override the style from **generic.xaml**. This is a part of it but I guess you can start to modify here.

```xml
<!--  Top nav ItemsRepeater  -->
<ItemsRepeaterScrollHost
    Grid.Column="3"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <ScrollViewer
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <ItemsRepeater
            x:Name="TopNavMenuItemsHost"
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Content"
            AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation"
            AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}">
            <ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                <!--Try using UniformGridLayout instead of StackLayout-->
                <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />-->
                <UniformGridLayout
                    ItemsStretch="Fill"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsRepeater.Layout>
        </ItemsRepeater>
    </ScrollViewer>
</ItemsRepeaterScrollHost>
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, that spacing is still there except now it is between MenuItems and FooterMenuItems is it possible to remove it entirely

Comment: You can modify the style but you have to bring a bunch of code from **generic.xaml**. I just updated my answer with a part of it.